# Spring MongoTemplate - find by regex in collection

Tags: java, regex, spring, mongodb, mongotemplate

Saying i have a multivalue field in a mongo document:

```
public class MongoEntity{
    private List<String> field;
}
```

What would be the correct [criteria](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Criteria.html) for querying a regex in that field?

I've tried

```
Criteria.where(searchText).regex(searchText).in("field");
```

But that results in

```
org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: 
Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown top level operator: $in; 
nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoException: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown top level operator: $in
```

Comment: How did you solve the problem? it would be very helpful, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after many trial and errors, turns out it's simpler (although a little counter-intuitive in my opinion) than it thought:

```
Criteria.where("field").regex(searchText);
```

Comment: this is not working for me. I have List<String> tags and want to search with searchStr                       I have code like this      String regex = ".*" + searchText + ".*";  Criteria.where("tags").regex(regex). But this is not giving results.

Answer (score 0):

This is working

```
List<Pattern> regs = new ArrayList<Pattern>()
regs.add(Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE))
Criteria.where("tags").regex(regs)
```