# Search a list of text in an embedded array using Spring data Mongo

Tags: java, regex, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have to create a service which takes a list of text and searches for matches in an embedded array in documents in MongoDB. For example,
I have to search this list of text:

```
["Tom", "Keanu", "Arnold"]
```

in the following collections:

```
[{id: "123", title: "Movie 1", cast: [{id: 1, name: "Tom Hanks"}, {id: 2, name: "Actor 2"}]}, 
{id: "123", title: "Movie 1", cast: [{id: 1, name: "Keanu Reeves"}, {id: 2, name: "Actor 2"}]}
{id: "123", title: "Movie 1", cast: [{id: 1, name: "Arnold Schwarzenegger"}, {id: 2, name: "Actor 2"}]}]
```

Searching above text should return these three movies. It requires me to create a query like below:

```js
db.movies.find({cast.name: {$in: [/Tom/, /Keanu/, /Arnold/]}})
```

This is because according to [official doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#in-expressions), we cannot use `$regex` with `$in`. However I am not able to find a way to translate this into Spring Data Mongo query.

This [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35623672/spring-mongotemplate-find-by-regex-in-collection) thread explains how to search for a single text in an embedded array using regex but I couldn't find anything about searching from a given list in an embedded document using Spring data Mongo. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this using `$elemMatch` and regex criteria.  [$elemMatch equivalent in spring data mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28874941/elemmatch-equivalent-in-spring-data-mongodb)  has a good discussion of `$elemMatch` in spring data. Something like:

```
Criteria.where("cast").elemMatch(Criteria.where("name").regex("Tom|Keanu|Arnold"));
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks, marking this as the correct answer.